# Mysql Table Column Cannot Be Null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table with three columns, Id , Name , Quantity.
It appears that when I am trying to insert a row with at least one null column or when i am trying to set the default value of a column to NULL the database throws an error.
***#1048 - Column 'Quantity' cannot be null***

How can I set NULL as a valid value for a column?

Comment: Please show your current data structure.

Comment: Check "SQL_MODE='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';" exist in your my.ini

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY quantity NUMERIC(20, 2)
```

Replace `NUMERIC(20, 2)` with your actual datatype, but without `NOT NULL` constraint.

To show your current column definitions, run

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable
```

in `mysql` (the command line client)